# dialog sapui5 oError.body display Rendering

Tags: dialog, rendering, popover, sapui5

Hi I have a dialog witch should display the content of an error in the console from a button.

Inside a UPDATE CRUD I have a dialog witch should return me an error from the console if the operation is in a certain situation.
This is my code from the error function.

```
    function(oError){
        var StringoError = JSON.parse(oError.response.body);
        /*alert("Error!\n"+oError.message);*/
        alert(StringoError.error.message.value);
```

if I use the 2 alerts it works .. but now I have to style the user experience and put the content of Error.message and StringoError.error.message.value in a dialog/popover/popup.. so I implemented like this:

```
        var dialog = new Dialog({
            title: (oError.message),
            type: 'Message',
            state: 'Error',
            content: new Text({
                text: JSON.parse(oError.response.body).error.message.value,
            }),
            beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
                text: 'Close',
                press: function () {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }),
            afterClose: function() {
                dialog.destroy();
            }
        });

        dialog.open();

    });
```

The problem is that I get to see the title but I can't see error.message.value and the console gives me back as error:

> The renderer for class sap.ui.core.Control is not defined or does not
>   define a render function! Rendering of __control0 will be skipped!

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be `sap.m.Text`? Or are you using the AMD Module format? But you are using `sap.m.Button` in the same code...

```js
content: new sap.m.Text({
            text: JSON.parse(oError.response.body).error.message.value,
        }),
```